# How to change the position/view of relativelayout in android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a layout which has 3 `RelativeLayout`s which are placed as follows.

- RelativeLayout1
   -> other widgets and a `Switch`
- RelativeLayout2
   -> 2 `ImageButton`s placed vertically
- RelativeLayout3
   -> 2 `Button`s placed vertically

By default the state of the `Switch` is in the off state.

What I want is

1. When the `Switch` is in the off state RelativeLayout3 should be placed or should overlap RelativeLayout2, i.e the 3rd layout should come up at position 2
2. when the `Switch` is enabled (i.e in the on state), Relativelayout2 should be visible and Relativelayout3 should come below it.

Below is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bckgrnd_4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Task Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="@string/hint_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView7" />

     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/switch1" />

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Set Location"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/editText" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Always alert me"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative2"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:src="@drawable/cal"
            style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
            android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
            android:src="@drawable/alert"
            android:layout_marginStart="67dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Task"
            style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
            android:id="@+id/button6" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            style="@style/btnStyleBeige"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_marginStart="37dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a listener for the `Switch` and toggle the visibility of the layout based on whether the `Switch` is on or off. For example,

```
    Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);

    s.setOnCheckedChangedListener (this);

    ...
}

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    RelativeLayout relative2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative2);
    relative2.setVisibility(isChecked ? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);

}
```